# Generate single thumbnail for Photoshop *.psd files

Tags: imagemagick, jpeg, photoshop, psd, exiftool

I want to generate one single JPEG image file for PSD formats using any software.

I tried ImageMagick but it's converting every layer into different images.

I also tried exiftool. It got converted to one single image but quality is very bad.

This is my code in ImageMagick:

```
convert filename.psd -thumbnail 340x340 testing.jpg
```

This is exiftool :

```
exiftool -Photoshop:PhotoshopThumbnail -b -resize filename.psd >z1.jpg
```

Answer (score 5):

I got this answer:

```
convert filename.psd -flatten -quality 100 z.jpg
```

We can change the quality parameter.

Answer (score 2):

To generate *thumbnails*, you should run:

```
 convert filename.psd -flatten -thumbnail 340x340 filename-thumb.jpg
```

or

```
 convert filename.psd -flatten -thumbnail 340x    filename-thumb.png
```

or

```
 convert filename.psd -flatten -thumbnail    x340 filename-thumb.gif
```

or similar. *(Find out yourself what the different sizes will be when varying between `340x340`, `340x` and `x340`.)*

***Note,*** the key parameter to get rid of the unwanted *'1 image per layer'* output: you have to insert `-flatten` into the command.

Answer (score 1):

Vipsthumbnail in libvips can do this:

```
Vipsthumbnail filename.psd --size 300x
```

See the [libvips docs](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/Using-vipsthumbnail.md.html)

and if it's ok for you just to use the psd embedded thumbnail (as small as 160x160 in px),
it's super fast to extract thumbnail image with psd-tools:

```py
from psd_tools import PSDImage   
PSDImage.open('filename.psd').thumbnail().save("thumb.png")
```